# Difficulties with Pointers in C++ / Linking error

Tags: c++, boost, linker-errors, shared-ptr, quantlib

When compiling my code I get the following error:

> LNK2019   unresolved external symbol "public: class QuantLib::Matrix
>   const & __cdecl SachLib::AWDCalculator::RSB(void)const "
>   (?RSB@AWDCalculator@SachLib@@QEBAAEBVMatrix@QuantLib@@XZ) referenced
>   in function "protected: void __cdecl
>   SachLib::CalculationEngine_Sach::set_results(class
>   boost::shared_ptr &)const "
>   (?set_results@CalculationEngine_Sach@SachLib@@IEBAXAEAV?$shared_ptr@VAWDCalculator@SachLib@@@boost@@@Z)

It is found in CalculationEngine_Sach.obj in line 1.

Here is my code:

Abwicklungsdreieck and Gewichtungsfaktoren basically consists out of a Matrix and are obtained by its respective Reader. I think the names of their methods are unambiguous.

main.cpp:

```
#include "AbwicklungsdreieckReader.h"
#include "Abwicklungsdreieck.h"
#include "GewichtungsfaktorenReader.h"
#include "Gewichtungsfaktoren.h"
#include "Tarif_Sach.h"
#include "CalculationEngine_Sach.h"
#include "CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1.h"


#if defined(QL_ENABLE_SESSIONS)
namespace QuantLib {
    Integer sessionId() { return 0; }
}
#endif

using namespace QuantLib;
using namespace SachLib;


int main()
{
    std::cout << "\n\n\nTest Chain-Ladder-Verfahren\n\n";

    std::string input1 = "C:/Users/D91476/Desktop/LifeLib_Sol/awd.csv";
    std::string input2 = "C:/Users/D91476/Desktop/LifeLib_Sol/gwf.csv";


    boost::shared_ptr<PricingEngine> EngineTyp1(new CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1());

    SachLib::AbwicklungsdreieckReader input1Reader(input1);
    SachLib::GewichtungsfaktorenReader input2Reader(input2);

    SachLib::Abwicklungsdreieck AWD = input1Reader.get_awd();
    std::cout << "\nInput 1: Abwicklungsdreieck\n\n";
    std::cout << AWD.get_Matrix() << "\n";

    SachLib::Gewichtungsfaktoren GWF = input2Reader.get_gwf();
    std::cout << "\nInput 2: Gewichtungsfaktoren\n\n";
    std::cout << GWF.get_Matrix();

    Tarif_Sach *tarifsach1;
    tarifsach1 = new Tarif_Sach_Typ1(AWD, GWF);

    tarifsach1->setPricingEngine(EngineTyp1);
    EngineTyp1->calculate();
}
```

By testing I found out that the error appears because of the following line:

```
boost::shared_ptr<PricingEngine> EngineTyp1(new CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1());
```

AWDCalculator.h

```
#pragma once

#include "Tarif_Sach.h"
#include "Abwicklungsdreieck.h"
#include "Gewichtungsfaktoren.h"

#ifndef _AWDCalculator_H
#define _AWDCalculator_H

namespace SachLib {

    class AWDCalculator {
    public:
        AWDCalculator();
        AWDCalculator(Tarif_Sach::arguments *arguments);
        AWDCalculator(Abwicklungsdreieck awd, Gewichtungsfaktoren gwf);
        AWDCalculator(const AWDCalculator &obj);
        AWDCalculator& operator=(AWDCalculator const& rhs);


        //! Fills vectors.
        void update(Tarif_Sach::arguments *arguments);

        // Logic
        void calculate(Abwicklungsdreieck awd, Gewichtungsfaktoren gwf);

        //! \name Getter
        //@{
        const Abwicklungsdreieck& awd() const;
        const Gewichtungsfaktoren& gwf() const;
        const Matrix& estimated_costs_matrix() const;
        const Matrix& RSB_all() const;
        const Matrix& RSB() const;
        //@}

        Tarif_Sach::arguments *arguments_;

    protected:
        AWDCalculator *results_;
        Abwicklungsdreieck awd_;
        Gewichtungsfaktoren gwf_;

        //!  \name Outputs
        //@{
        Matrix estimated_costs_matrix_;
        Matrix RSB_all_;
        Matrix RSB_;
        //@}

    };

}

#endif
```

AWDCalculator.cpp

```
#include "AWDCalculator.h"


SachLib::AWDCalculator::AWDCalculator()
{
}

SachLib::AWDCalculator::AWDCalculator(Tarif_Sach::arguments *arguments)
    : AWDCalculator(arguments->awd, arguments->gwf)
{
    arguments_ = arguments;
}

SachLib::AWDCalculator::AWDCalculator(Abwicklungsdreieck awd, Gewichtungsfaktoren gwf)
    : awd_(awd),
    gwf_(gwf)
{
    results_ = new AWDCalculator(awd, gwf);
    calculate(awd, gwf);
}

SachLib::AWDCalculator::AWDCalculator(const AWDCalculator& obj)
{
    arguments_ = obj.arguments_;
    awd_ = obj.awd_;
    gwf_ = obj.gwf_;
}

SachLib::AWDCalculator& SachLib::AWDCalculator::operator=(AWDCalculator const& rhs)
{
    arguments_ = rhs.arguments_;
    awd_ = rhs.awd_;
    gwf_ = rhs.gwf_;

    return *this;
}


void SachLib::AWDCalculator::update(Tarif_Sach::arguments *arguments)
{
    results_ = new AWDCalculator(arguments);
    arguments_ = arguments;
    awd_ = arguments->awd;
    gwf_ = arguments->gwf;
}

void SachLib::AWDCalculator::calculate(Abwicklungsdreieck awd, Gewichtungsfaktoren gwf)
{
    // RSB_, RSB_all_ and estimated_costs_matrix_ get calculated here with the input awd and gwf
}

inline const Matrix& SachLib::AWDCalculator::estimated_costs_matrix() const
{
    return estimated_costs_matrix_;
}

inline const Matrix& SachLib::AWDCalculator::RSB_all() const
{
    return RSB_all_;
}

inline const Matrix& SachLib::AWDCalculator::RSB() const
{
    return RSB_;
}

inline const SachLib::Abwicklungsdreieck& SachLib::AWDCalculator::awd() const
{
    return awd_;
}

inline const SachLib::Gewichtungsfaktoren& SachLib::AWDCalculator::gwf() const
{
    return gwf_;
}
```

CalculationEngine_Sach.h

```
#pragma once

#ifndef SachLib_calculationengine_sach_hpp
#define SachLib_calculationengine_sach_hpp

#include "Tarif_Sach.h"
#include "AWDCalculator.h"

using namespace QuantLib;

namespace SachLib {

    class CalculationEngine_Sach : public Tarif_Sach::engine {
    public:
        CalculationEngine_Sach();
        void calculate() const;

    protected:
        mutable boost::shared_ptr<AWDCalculator> AWDCalculator_;

        void set_results(boost::shared_ptr<AWDCalculator> &awdCalculator) const;

    };

}

#endif
```

CalculationEngine_Sach.cpp

```
#include "CalculationEngine_Sach.h"
#include "Tarif_Sach.h"
#include "AWDCalculator.h"


using namespace QuantLib;

namespace SachLib {

    CalculationEngine_Sach::CalculationEngine_Sach()
    {

    }

    void CalculationEngine_Sach::calculate() const
    {
        arguments_.AWDCalculator->update(&arguments_);

        CalculationEngine_Sach::set_results(arguments_.AWDCalculator);
    }

    void CalculationEngine_Sach::set_results(boost::shared_ptr<AWDCalculator> &awdCalculator) const
    {
        results_.estimated_costs_matrix = awdCalculator->estimated_costs_matrix();
        results_.RSB_all = awdCalculator->RSB_all();
        results_.RSB = awdCalculator->RSB();
        // because of the above three lines the error appears
    }
}
```

CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1.h

```
#pragma once
#include "CalculationEngine_Sach.h"

namespace SachLib {
    class CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1 : public CalculationEngine_Sach
    {
    public:
        CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1();
    };

}
```

CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1.cpp

```
#include "CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1.h"

SachLib::CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1::CalculationEngine_Sach_Typ1()
{}
```

If anyone could help I'd be much grateful.

Comment: `inline` methods should be implemented in header itself.

Comment: What is  QuantLib?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot to write, QuantLib is a namespace for the purpose of valuating financial instruments. I want to create my own instrument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You marked that function `inline` in the `.cpp`:

```
inline const Matrix& SachLib::AWDCalculator::RSB() const
```

In this case the compiler does not have to generate an out-of-line definition, unless it is needed in that translation unit (e.g. function address is taken). And that causes the linker error.

Remove `inline` from the function definition to make the compiler generate an out-of-line definition to fix the linker error.

Comment: I get a runtime error now though: Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8D7F59E08 in main.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::runtime_error at memory location 0x000000B5727AEB40.

Comment: @Stefan Ask a new question.

Comment: After some experimenting by myself I couldn't find a solution, I posted a new question which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174728/difficulties-with-pointers-in-c-runtime-error-quantlib

Answer (score -2):

you'll need to find the include file that has the definition for "Matrix" - that's what the error is showing.

Comment: That would be a preprocessor/compiler error, whereas this is a linker error.